# Can someone recommend a solid option to help me "get my feet wet"?

Tags: class

I've been interviewing with a company that uses Salesforce as their CRM.  I'm a sales professional and have had to use Seibel before but never salesforce.

I am hoping someone could **supply me with a site that would be a good way to learn the basics and familiarize myself with salesforce** so that I can hit the ground running.  **I thought there might be a site that sets the bar for such instances**.  I know I can stumble around looking at youtube, howtogeek, how to, lifehacker, makeuseof, etc. But I thought I might find a more informed answer in here. **Possibly that allows for me to work in an actual or simulated environ.**

I went over the questions and this is a not a subjective question, tagging though (I don't think class means a simulator but best I could find) made me wonder if this doesn't belong here? I don't know what better place to ask than the salesforce Q & A. Thanks for any help.  I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to the community.

signup for a free Developer Edition, which all comes with all available features (incl. Sales and Service Cloud) at
https://events.developerforce.com/signup?d=70130000000EjHb

you can find training videos, guides, ... in the Help Portal
http://help.salesforce.com/

Comment: @Sdry and Seb Thank you both.  This is precisely what I was hoping existed, but did not even think salesforce would actually offer such. If I land the job or get the next one this will surely help as salesforce seems to have set the standard.  Although people have heard of Siebel I haven't seen any job postings listing their CRM as preferred familiarity.

Comment: To be added to this list now is trailhead: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce itself provides these things through [developer.force.com](http://developer.force.com/). Using the site you can also register for a [free developer org](https://events.developerforce.com/signup?d=70130000000EnJ4) which roughly a tiny version of their unlimited version, execellent to explore the platform, play around and practise anything from the basics to apex and visualforce development.

On developer.force.com, have a look at the Technical Library tab, this contains most of the goodies such as documentation. To start with I recommend [enter link description here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook) the workbook section. The force.com workbook is a the best start.