# Learning app using Salesforce workbook

Tags: visualforce, community

Learning app using Salesforce workbook just started Salesforce. I'm learning to make any applicaiton using Salesforce workbook just to get the hold of it or learning new things.... 
Is there any app-exchange or workshop practice available for the beginners to learn? any blog or pdf or i can download the app-exchange and look at the code and pages how its been developed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone recommend a solid option to help me "get my feet wet"?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13241/can-someone-recommend-a-solid-option-to-help-me-get-my-feet-wet)

Comment: Please try [Salesforce Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead) -  the place to learn Salesforce.

Comment: Abu, this is a much asked question, which has been answered many times before (on this site and many others). Have you tried using a search engine ? There are many ways to start, but as of late the trailhead recommended by @villsiva is definitely the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Refer all the libraries even the Trial head is there among those. do some workbooks and go though the force.com , visualforce guides too. Below link can take you to most of the learning material

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/#!/feedtype=RECENT&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS